# Optimizing GraphClient Connection?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Below you will see my GraphOperations class (written in `C#` using `Neo4jClient`) that performs basic `Neo4j` graph operations. The `GraphGetConnection()` method connects to Neo4j and returns `clientConnection` and my `CreateNode()` method created a node and returns its node reference.

Now in that method you will see that Im going `GraphOperations graphOp = new GraphOperations();` and then `clientConnection= graphOp.GraphConnection();`.

1. Is this the right way to do this?
2. Do I call a connection every time I want to perform an operation?
3. How do I optimize this code below? I want to create a method for each CRUD operation and want to find the best way to do this.

I hope the question is clear enough?

```
using Neo4jClient;

public class GraphOperations
{
    GraphClient clientConnection;

    public GraphClient GraphGetConnection()
    {
        clientConnection = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        clientConnection.Connect();

        return clientConnection;
    }

    public long GraphCreateNode(string type, string name, string customerName, string documentReference, int newVersionNumber)
    {

        Guid nodeGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        string timeStamp = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dateTime);

        GraphOperations graphOp = new GraphOperations();
        clientConnection = graphOp.GraphGetConnection();

        var createNode = clientConnection.Create(new VersionNode()
        {
            GUID = nodeGuid.ToString(),
            Name = name,
            Type = type,
            DocumentReference = documentReference,
            DateTimeCreated = timeStamp,
            Version = newVersionNumber
        });

        return createNode.Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are already storing the `GraphClient` in the `GraphOperations` class, and as your `GraphCreateNode` method isn't static, you could just use that field, so your `GraphCreateNode` method becomes something like:

```
public long GraphCreateNode(string type, string name, string customerName, string documentReference, int newVersionNumber)
{
    /* CODE */
    this.GraphGetConnection(); //Don't care or need the return from GraphGetConnection
    //From then on just:
    clientConnection.DOSTUFF ....
    /* CODE */
```

Personally, I would change a few things to make life a bit easier for yourself:

```
public class GraphOperations 
{
    private GraphClient clientConnection;
    private void InitializeGraphClient()
    {
        if(this.clientConnection != null)
            return;

        this.clientConnection = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        this.clientConnection.Connect();
    }

    public NodeReference CreateNode(/*parameters*/) 
    {
        InitializeGraphClient();

        Guid nodeGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        string timeStamp = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dateTime);

        var createNode = this.clientConnection.Create(
            new VersionNode()
                    {
                        GUID = nodeGuid.ToString(),
                        Name = name,
                        Type = type,
                        DocumentReference = documentReference,
                        DateTimeCreated = timeStamp,
                        Version = newVersionNumber
                    });

        return createNode.Id;
    }
}
```

In each method (CRUD-wise) you'll call `InitializeGraphClient` and that will make sure the connection is there. The other way (and this might be preferable) is to stick that initialization into the constructor for `GraphOperations`:

```
public class GraphOperations 
{
    private readonly GraphClient clientConnection;
    public GraphOperations()
    {
        this.clientConnection = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        this.clientConnection.Connect();
    }

    public NodeReference CreateNode(/*parameters*/) 
    {
        Guid nodeGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        string timeStamp = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dateTime);

        var createNode = this.clientConnection.Create(
            new VersionNode()
                    {
                        GUID = nodeGuid.ToString(),
                        Name = name,
                        Type = type,
                        DocumentReference = documentReference,
                        DateTimeCreated = timeStamp,
                        Version = newVersionNumber
                    });

        return createNode.Id;
    }
}
```

and using that you should always know that the `GraphClient` instance will be there, which means your CRUD methods can focus on doing CRUD and not initializing the `GraphClient`. There is the potential with this that an `Exception` could be thrown from the constructor, but as to whether that is a bad thing or not is personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated, really helps stream line my code. What Exception/s could one expect as you have mentioned?

Comment: A good example would be an AggregateException (wrapping an inner exception of HttpRequestException) if you try running your code without the Neo4J Server being contactable. It's the reason that the Neo4jClient makes you call a 'connect' method after construction. But it's up to you to either follow the same approach, or just throw the Exception in the constructor...

Comment: I have seen that one before, could you please provide an example as to how you personally would handle this exception?

Comment: I don't do anything and just let it propagate to the calling code, I can't do anything about it, with no Neo4J server, there's nothing my code can do. If you can't do anything with an Exception, you should just let it be, something further down the line might be able to cope with it...